# Crystal Reports conflicting with css .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

the crystal reports i create from visual studio seem to be conflicting with the website format

This is how the menu should be
[image]
This is how it is coming with crystal reports loaded on the program

[image]

Any idea why its doing this?

Comment: I would add the CSS Code here, and maybe the CSS generated from the Crystal Reports

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Reports viewer renders everything into a control that exists on the page. In order to make it look the way it does they needed to add a virtual directory that you can see referenced if you right click and 'view source' on your webpage.

When you do this, you'll see the supporting directory referenced countless times to access everything from JavaScript files to images and CSS. (aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\crystalreportviewers13 is ONE example of the path you might see, depending on the version of Crystal Reports you are using).

My point here, is that the CSS referenced should fall under this path. The issue created on your site is likely due to an issue that arises from the way the CSS applies itself to the page. Unfortunately CSS, like JavaScript objects, can have conflicts with other elements on the page. They aren't "self contained" by nature.

A GREAT way to see the *exact* location of the CSS causing issues is to install the Web Developer add-on for FireFox or Internet Explorer. With this installed you can go to the 'CSS' menu and actually view the list of CSS files affecting the site. In fact, you can even disable CSS by location and see how it affects the page LIVE. You can also click on objects in the page and it'll expose details about the CSS applied to the objects. Alternatively or as well, you can install the FireBug add-on. It's got a great UI and can give you other tools for investigating it.

Good luck isolating the CSS. Once you've found it you'll need to either adjust your existing CSS to avoid it, use !Important tags to override their styles, or some combination of mark-up and CSS adjustments. I don't recommend adjusting the Crystal Report Viewer's CSS, it's safer and more maintainable to edit YOUR CSS to avoid the issue.